# How do I add a glyphicon into my HTML page title?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am looking into adding a glyphicon in my page title (not a favicon). I've tried `<title>Portal - <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"> Network</span></title>` yet it just shows the `<span>` element as plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can only add unicode symbols and emoji in the `<title>` tag.

> It can only contain text, and any contained tags are ignored.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Comment: Thanks, I found a unicde symbol for a globe and will use that instead. Although, it seems to appear in color.

Comment: Oh, weird. I wonder if your OS is replacing it with an emoji? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It may be, I'm coding on a chromebook currently.